# Using EXISTS within a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Is it possible to do the following:
I have a table that looks like this:

```
declare @tran_TABLE TABLE(
EOMONTH DATE,
AccountNumber INT,
CLASSIFICATION_NAME VARCHAR(50),
Value Float

)

INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2018-11-30','123','cat1',10)
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2018-11-30','123','cat1',15)
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2018-11-30','123','cat1',5 )
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2018-11-30','123','cat2',10)
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2018-11-30','123','cat3',12)
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2019-01-31','123','cat1',5 )
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2019-01-31','123','cat2',10)
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2019-01-31','123','cat2',15)
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2019-01-31','123','cat3',5 )
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2019-01-31','123','cat3',2 )
INSERT INTO @tran_TABLE VALUES('2019-03-31','123','cat1',15)


EOMONTH     AccountNumber   CLASSIFICATION_NAME     Value
2018-11-30  123                     cat1                10
2018-11-30  123                     cat1                15
2018-11-30  123                     cat1                5
2018-11-30  123                     cat2                10
2018-11-30  123                     cat3                12
2019-01-31  123                     cat1                5
2019-01-31  123                     cat2                10
2019-01-31  123                     cat2                15
2019-01-31  123                     cat3                5
2019-01-31  123                     cat3                2
2019-03-31  123                     cat1                15
```

I want to produce a result where it will check whether in each month, for each AccountNumber (just one in this case) there exists a CLASSIFICATION_NAME cat1, cat2, cat3.
If all 3 exist for the month, then return 1 but if any are missing return 0.

The result should look like:

```
EOMONTH     AccountNumber   CLASSIFICATION_NAME
2018-11-30    123                   1                               
2019-01-31    123                   1                       
2019-03-31    123                   0
```

But I want to do it as compactly as possible, without first creating a table that groups everything by CLASSIFICATION_NAME, EOMONTH and AccountNumber and then selects from that table.
For example, in the pseudo code below, is it possible to use maybe an `EXISTS` statement to do the group by?

```
SELECT 
    EOMONTH
    ,AccountNumber
    ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (CLASSIFICATION_NAME = 'cat1' AND 'cat2' AND 'cat3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 end 
    ,SUM(Value) AS totalSpend
FROM @tran_TABLE
GROUP BY 
    EOMONTH
    ,AccountNumber
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could emulate this behavior by counting the distinct classifications that answer this condition (per group):

```
SELECT 
    EOMONTH
    ,AccountNumber
    ,CASE COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN classification_name IN ('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3') THEN classification_name END) 
          WHEN 3 THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
     END
    ,SUM(Value) AS totalSpend
FROM @tran_TABLE
GROUP BY 
    EOMONTH
    ,AccountNumber
```

Comment: Works beautifully now https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3838136fd68177d5b6a69b8c5ae36214

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT EOMONTH, 
AccountNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT CLASSIFICATION_NAME) = 3 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END CLASSIFICATION_NAME
FROM @tran_TABLE
GROUP BY EOMONTH,AccountNumber
```

Output is-

```
2018-11-30  123 1
2019-01-31  123 1
2019-03-31  123 0
```

Comment: This will only work if there are no other classifications other than cat1, cat2 and cat3. If there could be, you'll need another condition - see my answer for details.

Comment: @Mureinik You just need to update the number 3 as your total number of classification. You can not make it dynamic unless you manage separate list for classification. In your solution, you have to change the list of Classification and Also the Number 3 you used whenever there changes comes. Indeed your and mine solution is almost same.

Comment: @Mureinik in addition - Your solution will not also work if new Cat4 added in the classification list, Right?

Answer (score 1):

Query like this. You can count distinct values.
When you count unique values then column 'Three_Unique_Cat'. When you count exactly 'cat1','cat2','cat3' then column 'Three_Cat1_Cat2_Cat3'

```
SELECT 
    EOMONTH, AccountNumber
    ,CASE WHEN
       COUNT(DISTINCT CLASSIFICATION_NAME)=3 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Three_Unique_Cat'
    ,CASE WHEN 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION_NAME IN ('cat1','cat2','cat3') 
        THEN CLASSIFICATION_NAME ELSE NULL END)=3 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
     END AS 'Three_Cat1_Cat2_Cat3'
    ,SUM(Value) AS totalSpend
FROM @tran_TABLE
GROUP BY EOMONTH, AccountNumber 

Output:
EOMONTH   AccountNumber Three_Unique_Cat    Three_Cat1_Cat2_Cat3    totalSpend
2018-11-30  123 1   1   52
2019-01-31  123 1   1   37
2019-03-31  123 0   0   15
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just as below:

```
select
    EOMONTH,
    AccountNumber,
    case when count(distinct CLASSIFICATION_NAME) = 3 then 1 else 0 end as CLASSIFICATION_NAME
from
    tran_TABLE
group by
    EOMONTH,
    AccountNumber
```

Comment: What does this add to the basically identical answer posted by @mkRabbani?

Comment: OK,I see. When I was editing this answer, this page has not been updated.